# Data is not getting added to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been following this Tutorial for the Realtime Database, this tutorial was last Updated 31 Dec 2020, from [GeeksForGeeks-how-to-save-data-to-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-android](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-save-data-to-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-android/)
but for me the Data is not getting Added in the Database

**I've used the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio**
[image: I've used the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio]

**This is the MainActivity,** It has only 2 buttons which go to the activities for adding Data and Viewing them

[image: Main Activity]

Java File for MainActivity:

```
package com.anurag.newemsapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAdd, btnView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnView = findViewById(R.id.btnView);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
        
      // the View button is disabled for time-being

    }
}
```

**The Add Activity,** This is where, I take user input and try to save the data in Firebase

[image: AddActivity]

**Java File for AddActivity**

```
package com.anurag.newemsapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText etAddEid, etAddEname;
    private Button btnAddSave;


    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    Employee employee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        etAddEid = findViewById(R.id.etAddEid);
        etAddEname = findViewById(R.id.etAddEname);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Employee");

        employee = new Employee();

        btnAddSave = findViewById(R.id.btnAddSave);

        btnAddSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String id = etAddEid.getText().toString();
                String name = etAddEname.getText().toString();

                if (id.length() == 0 && name.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Please add some data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    addDataToFirebase(id, name);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDataToFirebase(String id, String name) {
        employee.setEmployeeId(id);
        employee.setEmployeeName(name);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                databaseReference.push().setValue(employee);
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Fail to add data " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now When I press the Save Button, it does the validation part but, addDataToFirebase doesn't seem to work.
I doesn't throw an error, the app runs perfectly fine. it's just the data that is not being added to Firebase Realtime Database

*I have added the google-services.json file in the project level, after manually downloading it from the firebase console*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, The solution to this was,

Pass the Database URL to the FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() function. Which you can find on your Firebase Console. You are suppoused to do it only if the Database location is set anything other than `US-Central`.

I had My database setup on `asia-southeast1`, as instructed on the **Android Studio Firebase Assistant**

[image: Firebase Assistant point 4]

I just had to add the Database URL to the FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() function, like so,
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(URL)`